# Align div (selection list) under input field

Tags: html, css, input

Hi I've got the following code:

```
<div class="hint-wrapper">
    <form>
        <label>Suggestions:</label>
        <input type="text" id="input-field">
        <div class="datalist-wrapper">
            <select class="availableDataSelection" multiple=""></select>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

It looks like this:
[image]

Now I want align the selection list (datalist-wrapper element) under the input field. It should also have the same width as the input field.

I already tried several CSS stuff like this:

```
.datalist-wrapper {
    float: left;
}

#input-field {
    float: left;
}
```

I want to achieve this:
[image]

Comment: Possible to change HTML?

Comment: Yes this would be possible @Aziz

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wrap the `input` and `select` element around a `div`, apply `position: relative` to the parent and `position: absolute` to the child (`select`) element so it could adapt parent element's width.

```css
#input {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.datalist-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.datalist-wrapper select {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="hint-wrapper">
  <form>
    <label>Suggestions:</label>
    <div id="input">
      <input type="text" id="input-field" />
      <div class="datalist-wrapper">
        <select class="availableDataSelection" multiple="">
          <option>a1</option>
          <option>a2</option>
          <option>a3</option>
          <option>a4</option>
          <option>a5</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this: put the input and select in a container div

```css
#input-field {
  width: 100%
}

label {
  float: left
}

.ct-input {
  width: 220px;
  float: left;
}

.datalist-wrapper {
  width: 100%
}

.datalist-wrapper select {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="hint-wrapper">
  <form>
    <label>Suggestions:</label>
    <div class="ct-input">
      <input type="text" id="input-field">
      <div class="datalist-wrapper">
        <select class="availableDataSelection" multiple=""></select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8kqz4gqg/

Comment: Thanks! This looks really good but the select list doesn't have the exact same width as the input field, as you can see here: https://i.imgur.com/lHNBTdC.png